# How do I keep track of a transaction from paykey request to IPN response?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paykey

I'm trying to implement the flow "**Setting Up Web Pages to Invoke the Embedded Payment Flow Using a Lightbox**" described here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

I'm able to get the initial paykey and I get as response something like this:

```
{u'responseEnvelope': {u'ack': u'Success', u'timestamp': u'2013-08-06T01:59:32.228-07:00', u'build': u'6941298', u'correlationId': u'3f9b3609b9069'}, u'paymentExecStatus': u'CREATED', u'payKey': u'AP-4C138527MX750433P'}
```

At this point we are able to display a "Pay with PayPal" button on our website, follow the payment etc.... the problem is now with IPN notification.

I've tried the IPN simulator and what it sends is a POST with these values (for example):

```
Key: last_name - Value: Smith
Key: txn_id - Value: 245929950
Key: receiver_email - Value: seller@paypalsandbox.com
Key: payment_status - Value: Completed
Key: tax - Value: 2.02
Key: residence_country - Value: US
Key: invoice - Value: abc1234
Key: address_state - Value: CA
Key: payer_status - Value: verified
Key: txn_type - Value: web_accept
Key: address_country - Value: United States
Key: payment_date - Value: 01:43:47 6 Aug 2013 PDT
Key: first_name - Value: John
Key: item_name - Value: something
Key: address_street - Value: 123, any street
Key: mc_gross1 - Value: 12.34
Key: custom - Value: xyz123
Key: notify_version - Value: 2.1
Key: address_name - Value: John Smith
Key: test_ipn - Value: 1
Key: item_number - Value: AK-1234
Key: receiver_id - Value: seller@paypalsandbox.com
Key: business - Value: seller@paypalsandbox.com
Key: payer_id - Value: TESTBUYERID01
Key: verify_sign - Value: AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A.8pFOgHmGMTg8Lj.JUvXyp3bu63
Key: address_zip - Value: 95131
Key: address_country_code - Value: US
Key: address_city - Value: San Jose
Key: address_status - Value: confirmed
Key: mc_fee - Value: 0.44
Key: mc_currency - Value: USD
Key: shipping - Value: 3.04
Key: payer_email - Value: buyer@paypalsandbox.com
Key: payment_type - Value: echeck
Key: mc_gross - Value: 12.34
Key: quantity - Value: 1
```

The fact is that our server that accept IPN posts must be able to accept any number of transactions. So, when I receive a message like this, how do I know which **paykey** is related to?

1) I could track the payment with payer_email, but what if the payer wants to login and pay with a different PayPal account?

2) What happens if there are two pending payments from the same PayPal account?

3) What if the payer doesn't want to create a PayPal account and want to pay with his credit card?

In these three situations I would not be able to connect the IPN message received to my initial transaction (that I identify with the paykey).

It looks like I'm missing something.... can anyone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass a custom variable to `Paypal` when the user goes there from your site, that gets returned to your IPN when the transaction is complete, you want to use the `custom` field in the button.

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="paykey:aBjKmNi223">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" border="0"     name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

And your IPN response will look like this...

```
Key: last_name - Value: Smith
Key: txn_id - Value: 245929950
Key: receiver_email - Value: seller@paypalsandbox.com
Key: custom - Value: paykey:aBjKmNi223
```

Note this only works for the field called `custom`. You cannot use just any field. If you want to pass multiple objects, use a comma-delineated string in the custom field.

Comment: I've a doubt: if I consider the transaction already started and I insert a row in my database... what happens if the user simply reload the page? A new paykey would be retrived and inserted in the database, waiting for the transaction to complete. The user could start as many transactions he wants and I would have to manage them all because I cannot know in advance if he will cancel them or not. What's the best practice in these cases?

Comment: Yes it is true, the user can create unlimited purchase instances just by refreshing the page again and again. However, if you assign a randomly generated key, this will only become a problem if *a) you run out of database space,* or *b) you run out of randomly generated keys.* Since neither of these are likely, you are ok to go for it.

In the odd case that space is a restriction, you can create a cronjob that automatically deletes entries that were created more than 30 days ago.